# Accessing an object from another thread

Tags: java, multithreading

I've got 2 classes (1 is a basic class, 2nd one extends Thread class) and I'm trying to access an object (class) that is initialized in my thread class on `run()` using `setText()`

```
public class TThread extends Thread{

        Patcher pf;

        public TThread(String string) {
            setName(string);
            start();
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            pf = new Patcher("Checking Serial key..."); //<=== Class initialized here in a separate thread
        }

        public void setText(String string) {
            pf.setText(string); //<=== Trying to access patcher here, throws NullPointerException
        }
}
```

This is how I call `TThread`

```
public void myCall(){
   TThread tpf = new TThread("pf thread");
   //some code later
   try{
       tpf.setText("blabla");
   }
```

The `pf.setText()` throws `NullPointerException` when I'm trying to access patcher from another thread.

How can I get to that thread and access patcher from another class or this class?

Comment: Is is rather unusual to have only constructor in the `run` method, are you sure you call `setText()` *after* calling `yourTThreadObject.start()`?

Comment: @kajacx I'm sure I'm not calling `setText()` before the `start()`. I initialize my thread class in one class and 10ish lines later I call `setText()`.

Answer (score 4):

This is classic race condition. Because you have two threads, there is no guarantee what will happen first. `pf` might be accessed by main thread before it's initialized by a background thread.

Right now, your program is unpredictable. Try adding `Thread.sleep(100);` at the beginning of  `setText` method. It will appear to work correctly, but it might still fail in some specific circumstances.

One way to fix it is to wait in main thread until `pf` is initialized:

```
@Override
public synchronized void run() {
    pf = new Patcher("Checking Serial key...");
    notifyAll();
}

public synchronized void setText(String string) throws InterruptedException {
    while(pf==null) {
        wait();
    }
    pf.setText(string);
}
```

Be careful. If you have not worked with threads before, it might be tricky to get right.

Answer (score 1):

It is a time consuming process to start a new Thread. With a small delay your code will execute successfully:

TThread thread = new TThread("str");

**Thread.sleep(1000);**

thread.setText("str2");

So the problem is that your thread had no time to execute the run method (and create the instance). You should check the existance of the instance, and wait for it's creation in the setText method - or instantiate it in the TThread's constructor.